# How can I make this happen when page loads?

Tags: javascript

I work as an intern with Ruby on Rails and yesterday I had to do something with Javascript (my javascript skills ARE AWFUL, I DON'T EVEN HAVE SKILLS with IT).

I implemented current location feature in a project, but I'd like to do it another way... the thig is kinda done, take a look:

```
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]){
        var user_address = results[0].formatted_address;
        document.getElementById("current_location").innerHTML = user_address;
      }else {
        console.log('No results found for these coords.');
      }
    }else {
      console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function geolocationError() {
  console.log("please enable location for this feature to work!");
}

$(document).on("ready page:ready", function() {
  $("#current-location").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation not supported!");
    }
  });
});
```

All right, I know it all happens when I click the button with Id="current-location", but I'd like it to happen automatically when the page loads, how can I do it?

Comment: I made a mistake
I sent the wrong version of the code
I will try to edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply insert the code you want executed inside of a `$(document).ready(` block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation not supported!");
    }
});
```

On a side note, I would recommend *not* naming a function variable `event` since event is a keyword.  The standard convention for passing event to a function is to use `e`.  For example:

```
$('#someId').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It solved!
and yes... I HAVE to study js